# More efficient way than zipping arrays for transposing a table in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, transpose

I have been trying to transpose my table of 2000000+ rows and 300+ columns on a cluster, but it seems that my Python script is getting killed due to lack of memory. I would just like to know if anyone has any suggestions on a more efficient way to store my table data other than using the array, as shown in my code below?

```
import sys
Seperator = "\t"
m = []
f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
data = f.read()
lines = data.split("\n")[:-1]
for line in lines:
    m.append(line.strip().split("\t"))
for i in zip(*m):
    for j in range(len(i)):
        if j != len(i):
            print(i[j] +Seperator)
        else:
            print(i[j])
    print ("\n")
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: if your data is numerical, just use numpy

Comment: Are you able to keep the entire array in memory before transposing? Just want to know where the code is actually running out of memory.

Comment: @Dunes Oh, I'm not able to finishing storing the entire array, it always gets killed towards the end of the 'm.append' step. Out of the 2379856 lines, the furthest I've gotten is 2321894 lines. I got the numbers by printing a number count after the append line.

Comment: @Julien thanks, it's alphanumerical unfortunately..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to note is that you've been careless with your variables. You're loading a large file into memory as a single string, and then a list of a strings, then a list of list of strings, before finally transposing said list. This will result in you storing all the data in the file three times before you even begin to transpose it.

If each individual string in the file is only about 10 characters long then you're going to need 18GB of memory just to store that (2e6 rows * 300 columns * 10 bytes * 3 duplicates). This is before you factor in all the overhead of python objects (~27 bytes per string object).

You have a couple of options options here.

- create each new transposed row incrementally by reading over the file once for each old row and appending each new row one at a time (sacrifices time efficiency).
- create one file for each new row and combine these row files at the end (sacrifices disk space efficiency, possibly problematic if you have a lot of columns in the initial file due to a limit of the number of open files a process may have).

### Transposing with a limited number of open files

```
delimiter = ','

input_filename = 'file.csv'
output_filename = 'out.csv'

# find out the number of columns in the file
with open(input_filename) as input:
    old_cols = input.readline().count(delimiter) + 1

temp_files = [
    'temp-file-{}.csv'.format(i)
    for i in range(old_cols)
]

# create temp files
for temp_filename in temp_files:
    open(temp_filename, 'w') as output:
        output.truncate()
with open(input_filename) as input:
    for line in input:
        parts = line.rstrip().split(delimiter)
        assert len(parts) == len(temp_files), 'not enough or too many columns'
        for temp_filename, cell in zip(temp_files, parts):
            with open(temp_filename, 'a') as output:
                output.write(cell)
                output.write(',')

# combine temp files
with open(output_filename, 'w') as output:
    for temp_filename in temp_files:
        with open(temp_filename) as input:
            line = input.read().rstrip()[:-1] + '\n'
            output.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the number of columns is far smaller than nuber of rows I would consider writing each column to separate file. And then combine them together.

```
import sys
Separator = "\t"
f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for line in f:
   for i, c in enumerate(line.strip().split("\t")):
      dest = column_file[i]  # you shoud open 300+ file handlers, one for each column
      dest.write(c)
      dest.write(Separator)

# all you need to do after than is combine the content of you "row" files
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot store all of your file into memory, you can read it n times:

```
column_number = 4  # if necessary, read the first line of the file to calculate it
seperetor = '\t'
filename = sys.argv[1]

def get_nth_column(filename, n):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if line:  # remove empty lines
                yield line.strip().split('\t')[n]


for column in range(column_number):
    print(seperetor.join(get_nth_column(filename, column)))
```

Note that an exception will be raised if the file does not have the right format. You could catch it if necessary.

When reading files : use with construct, to ensure that your file will be closed. And iterate directly on the file, instead of reading the content first. It is more readable and more efficient.